# ANOVA and HSD tests from Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, statsmodels, anova

I'm looking for a method to perform an ANOVA and HSD tests from a dataframe in Python. I tried to read some examples on forums and tutorials but i didn't achieve to apply it to my work.

Here is a simple Pandas dataframe:

```
Date Density Hour  Repetition Glucose
A    HD      AM    1          6.7
A    HD      AM    2          6.8
A    HD      PM    2          9.6
A    HD      PM    3          11.9
B    HD      AM    1          23
B    HD      AM    2          18.1
B    HD      PM    1          43.3
B    HD      PM    2          32
C    HD      AM    1          5.1
C    HD      AM    2          3.8
C    HD      PM    1          5.2
C    HD      PM    2          5.5
```

How could I perform an ANOVA and then an HSD test to inspect the effects of Date, Density and Hour on Glucose?
I tried with those libraries:

```
from scipy.stats import f_oneway
from statsmodels.stats.multicomp import pairwise_tukeyhsd
```

but i can't achieve to apply them to my example

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 1):

`pairwise_tukeyhsd` only allows a single group variable, it is for oneway ANOVA. It is possible to make all pairwise comparisons for all fully interacted groups after creating a group index for all different explanatory variables. For example `group1 = (A, HD, AM, 1)`, `group2 = (A, HD, AM, 2)`, and so on.

For pairwise comparison for only some effects, we would need the pairwise comparison after estimating the multiway ANOVA with OLS. This is currently not available in statsmodels. The critical values and p-values of Tukey-HSD would not apply in that case.

What would be possible in this case is to estimate the full model with OLS, define all desired pairwise contrasts, use the `t_test` to get the raw p-values for the comparisons, and then apply one of the multiple p-value corrections that are available.